# Performing two count functions on an RDD in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Given an RDD with tuples like

```
(key1, 0)
(key2, 5)
(key3, 11)
(key1, 44)
(key2, 0)
(key3, 43)
(key1, 0)
(key2, 5)
(key3, 33)
```

For each `key`, I wish to count 2 values, total count of values per key, or regular output of `countByKey()`, and second count, count of positive numbers by key.

So the result would be like:

```
[(key1, 3, 1),
(key2, 3, 2),
(key3, 3, 3)]
```

I would like to use only `map` and `reduceByKey` functions:

```
def map(value):
    return (value[0], (value[1], 1, 1))
```

return a key value pair, where value is the triple of the numerical value, and two integers used for counting

```
def reduce(val1, val2):
    # if value[0] is positive, increment first counter
    # in any case, always increment second counter

data.map(map).reduceByKey(reduce).collect()
```

would then be something like:

```
[(key1, 3, 1),
(key2, 3, 2),
(key3, 3, 3)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if value is positive or not in the `map` step and assign `1` if `> 0` else `0`. Then, reduce by key and sum like this:

```
rdd1 = data.map(lambda x: (x[0], (1, int(x[1] > 0)))) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]))

for k in rdd1.collect():
    print(k)

#('key1', (3, 1))
#('key2', (3, 2))
#('key3', (3, 3))
```

Comment: Assuming the constraint to only use `map` and `reduceByKey` this is the best answer I could also think of.
However, I would look into `aggregateByKey` as well

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly something like this:

```
def reduce(val1, val2):
    if val2[0] > 0: # val1 is the accumulator, val2 the new datum
        return (val1[0], val1[1] + 1, val1[2] + 1)
    else:
        return (val1[0], val1[1] + 1, val1[2])

data.map(map).reduceByKey(reduce).collect()
```

would work.